# How to call an exported typescript function from within javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ts-node

I have a typescript file with imports eg:

util.ts file

```
import { protractor } from 'protractor'

export const waitForFile = async () => {
 protractor.promise....
 return await ''
}
```

Now helper.js file

```
const getUtilFunction = (func) => {
  const { register } = require('ts-node');
  const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.json');
  register({ compilerOptions });
  const result = require('./utils.ts');
  return result[func];
};

const waitTillReportGenerated = async () => {
  const waitForFileToDownload = getUtilFunction('waitForFileToDownload');
  const file = await waitForFileToDownload('./result/result.js', 60000);
  console.log(file);
}
```

However when we call the helper.js function it throws error that protractor is undefined.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You're importing `xyz` but what is `protractor`? Do you need to import some sort of `protractor` declaration? If `xyz` is a function you call it like any other function.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad.. I have to import a function from protractor (xyz for eg:-) which i have to use in the exported function

Comment: In short the issue im facing is that with ts-node i am able to require the ts file but whenever the ts exported function is using imported functions it throws undefined

Comment: [UPDATED] I never had this kind of situation, but I think the Typescript declarations might be what you are looking for 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `.ts` file to `.js`.

Comment: Tried without brace. Same error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined

Dependencies are installed and i am using the util functions in other typescript files without any issue.

This error is only when i have to use the it directly in typescript file using ts-node

Comment: Your `helper` has the extension `.js`. Try updating the extension to `.ts`

Comment: That;s the thing. I cannot use .ts and it has to be a js file, which is why i need a way to use the util function.. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `ts-node`:
package.json
`
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0"
  }
`
run: `npm install`
change your `helper.js` to `helper.ts`
Then run: `ts-node helper.ts`

Comment: Or: is needed the file `util.ts` become `.ts`? can you try updating the extension to `.js`
The import should be updated to: `const protractor = require('protractor')`

Comment: That would be a lot of rework as the util.ts is 1000+ line file which is currently in .ts.. In fact 95% of my framework is in .ts except few .js which has to be used outside framework too.. Which is why i need the ability to call ts function inside js file

Comment: The files `.ts` are only for DEV and compilation time, NodeJs and browsers don't run `.ts` files, you need to convert `.ts` files to `.js`.

BUT: If you use `ts-node` you will be able to run `.ts` files in production environment.